# Check Sunday between two dates fall into predefined list in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have PySpark dataframe, with column of `start_date`, `end_date`. I need to check whether any Sunday between them fall into predefined dates list

```
holiday_Sundays_list = ['01/01/2023', '07/04/2027', '07/04/2032']


start_date   end_date   **Sunday_in_list**
05/01/2023   05/02/2023    N
04/26/2023   05/09/2023    N
12/28/2022   01/02/2023    Y
```

dataframe sample

[image]

I tried and didn't work, I am expecting to get column of Sunday_in_list column

Answer (score 0):

#### Code

```
# create an array of dates from holiday list
holidays = F.array([F.to_date(F.lit(c), 'MM/dd/yyyy') for c in holiday_Sundays_list])

# create an array/sequence of dates between each start_date and end_date
interval = F.sequence(F.to_date('start_date', 'MM/dd/yyyy'), F.to_date('end_date', 'MM/dd/yyyy'))

# Check whether two arrays overlaps
df = df.withColumn('sunday_in_list', F.arrays_overlap(interval, holidays))
```

#### Result

```
df.show()

+----------+----------+--------------+
|start_date|  end_date|sunday_in_list|
+----------+----------+--------------+
|05/01/2023|05/02/2023|         false|
|04/26/2023|05/09/2023|         false|
|12/28/2022|01/02/2023|          true|
+----------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for help, Shubham. The df is huge with a lot of rows . My question is : is there any way to integrate the step of "interval array" into the dataframe directly ?  Have a good day

Comment: Thank you Shubham, it works perfectly fine . Appreciate your help!